# Batch: Inputting text from one .txt into the line of a command in a different .bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

For a school project, we are learning to use PsTools. What I'm trying to do is run this command

```
@echo off
cls
:loop
psshutdown \\(computer_name) -u (Username) -p (password)
goto loop
```

I have the username of the test computer, but I do not have the password. The assignment is to figure out the password and input it into the command line. I have a program that makes passwords for me and saves them as a .txt file. Each line of the .txt file is a different possible password. How do I insert each line of the .txt file and run the command at the same time?

Comment: Read the help file for the `FOR` command by typing: `FOR /?` at a cmd prompt.

Comment: It's reading the FOR command as the password. @Squashman

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Comment: Sorry let me specify. It is using FOR as the password, not the lines from the text document. @Squashman

Comment: I see no changes to your code in your question, so I don't know what you are not understanding about using the `FOR` command. Please update your question with the code using the `FOR` command.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

for %%a /f in (password.txt) do psshutdown \\(computer_name) -u (Username) -p %%a
```